# Jumping to internal location in XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm generating a PDF using XSL.I want to display a link on Page-1 of my PDF which when clicked upon will make the PDF to jump to Page-3 or say a specific location on the PDF.

I'm creating a tag on Page-3 on a specified location as

```
<a id="first" name="@first">Click me </a>
```

And on Page-1 I'm trying to call it as

```
<a href ="#first">You jumped to me </a>
```

However, it is not working as nothing is happening.
I'm not even getting any error while generating PDF using the XSL.The PDF gets formed but my requirements are not met.

Comment: What do you generate PDFs with? XSLT alone does not output PDF. If by "XSL" you mean "XSL-FO", what FO processor are you working with?

Comment: Yes, I meant XSL:fo only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the required result by using

```
<fo:block id="page3position"  xsl:use-attribute-sets="style-Normal">
```

at the position where I wanted to jump and provided the link to it as

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="page3position">Click</fo:basic-link>
```